# Flutter - Cambiar imagen y texto al presionar un boton

Tags: flutter, dart

Al presionar el icono de siguiente, como puedo hacer que tome los valores del siguiente de la lista, es decir como cambiar los valores de los `Text` y `Image.network`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimalesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => AnimalesPageState();
}

class Animal {
  String ID;
  String nombre;
  String imagen;
  String cantidad;

  Animal(this.ID, this.nombre, this.imagen, this.cantidad);
}

class AnimalesPageState extends State<AnimalesPage> {
  final globalKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _cIndex = 0;

  void _incrementTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      _cIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final lista = [];
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "1",
        "Oso",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/573534886063030272/gqv3XyAZ_400x400.jpeg",
        "10"));
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "2",
        "Perro",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670027373090353153/gCBT8qLC_400x400.png",
        "20"));
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "3",
        "Puerco",
        "https://kisseskinah.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/img_57151.png?w=680",
        "30"));

    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildPrevButton(),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 160.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 16.0,
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    lista[0].imagen,
                    width: 100.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  lista[0].nombre,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  lista[0].cantidad,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            _buildNextButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNextButton() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("Next");
        },
        icon: new Icon(
          Icons.navigate_next,
          size: 40.0,
        ),
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPrevButton() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.navigate_before,
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: 40.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás en un StatefulWidget, solo tienes que refrescar el index y usarlo, ahora solo estás usando directamente el índice 0.

También moví tu array de animales al método `initState`, para que la variable se pueda acceder en tus otros métodos y no solo en el build.

```dart
class AnimalesPageState extends State<AnimalesPage> {
  final globalKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _cIndex = 0;

  void _incrementTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      _cIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Animal> lista = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "1",
        "Oso",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/573534886063030272/gqv3XyAZ_400x400.jpeg",
        "10"));
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "2",
        "Perro",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/670027373090353153/gCBT8qLC_400x400.png",
        "20"));
    lista.add(new Animal(
        "3",
        "Puerco",
        "https://kisseskinah.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/img_57151.png?w=680",
        "30"));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildPrevButton(),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 160.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 16.0,
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    lista[_cIndex].imagen,
                    width: 100.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  lista[_cIndex].nombre,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  lista[_cIndex].cantidad,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            _buildNextButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNextButton() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("Next");
          setState(() {
            if (_cIndex < lista.length - 1) _cIndex++;
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.navigate_next,
          size: 40.0,
        ),
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPrevButton() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_cIndex > 0) _cIndex--;
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.navigate_before,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 40.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: genial bro, gracias. Hasta el previus lo hiciste :) esque soy un animal para programar jajaja. Saludos

Comment: jaja nada que ver, poco a poco, no dejes de practicar, te dejo el canal de youtube que tengo con un amigo sobre Flutter:  https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide